# Is it possible to unify Maxwell's four equations into one single equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

The ultimate goal of physics is to unify all the four fundamental forces together. These forces basically are laws of nature.
This makes me ask if it is possible or not to unify Maxwell's four laws?

[image]

Comment: FWIW, Maxwell's equations follow from an action principle.

Comment: Did you mean replacing all four laws of EM by one single equation or writing all four laws in a single compact notation?

Comment: What does the unification of the fundamental forces have to do with "unifying Maxwell's four laws"? What do you mean by "unify" here?

Comment: Also, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 12):

It basically boils down to how much maths you want to put into the notation.  For example in [Space-Time Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_algebra) notation, Maxwell's equations reduce to the single equation [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Geometric_algebra_formulations)]
$$
\nabla F = \mu_0 c J
$$

The geometric algebra approach is comparable to introducing one complex-valued equation instead of two real-valued ones, which requires that the problem to be "encoded" has the right structure.

Whether or not such condensed notation adds to the understanding is definitely a matter of taste and of debate, and it depends on how fluent a reader is in the respective notation.

Answer (score 5):

Maxwell's equations reflect several unrelated facts:

1. electromagnetism is a massless field emerging from charges and currents
2. the matter from which it emerges obeys charge-current conservation
3. fields in matter can be described using linear response theory

In vacuum point 3 is not relevant and a single equation can be written
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} =  j^\nu / \epsilon_0\,.$$
The field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ can be written as $\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$ so this becomes
$$\partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial_\nu \partial^\mu A^\mu =  j^\nu / \epsilon_0\,.$$
If you take $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$, the Lorenz condition, then
$$\partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu =  j^\nu / \epsilon_0\,.$$
The potential $A^\mu$ unifies $\bf E$ and $\bf B$.

Standard physics considers the Lorenz condition to be a choice of gauge.

Comment: How does your explanation give an answer to my question? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: ? It gives one single equation.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll the first equation in the post is the single equation equivalent to the four Maxwell's ones. The rest of the post is spent on defining the variables that appear in the equation in terms of objects you may be more familiar with

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll A unifies E and B.

Comment: It's still more than one equation though, because you define the equation containing the Maxwell's equations AND the Lorentz gauge condition as a constraint.

Comment: Well that is the main stream view that i don't share. For me the Lorenz condition is the consequence of charge conservation.

Comment: @my2cts could you explain this statement a bit more?

Comment: @my2cts It's pretty easy to show that the Maxwell equations are charge conserving independent of gauge.

Comment: @d_b Charge conservation is a property of  the source, not of the field. The easy proof that you are referring to shows that the Maxwell equations are _only valid_ when charge is conserved.

Comment: @Tom I take the last wave equation in my answer as the euler-lagrange equation following from the Fermi lagrangian. It then defines a 1-1 relation between source and field. Charge conservation then implies the Lorenz condition. See my paper (Eur. Phys. J. D, vol. 8, p 9-12 (2000)) at https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the paper if I have time.

Answer (score 2):

I will say it is difficult without hiding some equations elsewhere. If you want to keep $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf E$ it will be very complicated. With relativistic electromagnetism you can write two covariant equations
$$F^{\alpha\beta}_{~~~~~,\alpha}=\mu_0 J^\beta$$
where $J^\mu$ is the 4-current and
$$\partial_{\alpha}(\tfrac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}F_{\gamma\delta}) = 0$$
but then you have two define electromagnetic tensor $F^{\alpha\beta}$ in terms of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ which accounts for additional equations.

You could use electromagnetic potentials instead and write just
$$\partial_\beta\partial^\beta A^\alpha = \mu_0 J^\alpha$$
where $A^\alpha$ is the 4-potential. However this equation works only in the Lorenz gauge which adds an extra equation, and you need to have two other equations to explain how to derive $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf E$ from $A^\alpha$.

If you consider the Euler-Lagrange equations a different equation you could write the Lagrangian density as
$$\mathcal{L} ={\epsilon_0 \over 2} {E}^2 - {1 \over {2 \mu_0}} {B}^2   + \frac{1}{c}J_\alpha A^\alpha$$
but it is the same issue as the previous case because you still have $A^\alpha$.

More advanced mathematical notations may reduce it down to 2 (? not sure) if you are accustomed to their notation and properties of the operators. Note that you can always invent some new operator $T$, such that
$$T(\mathbf B ,\mathbf E,J^\alpha)=0$$
implies Maxwell's equations. However you will have to prove that $T$ is useful for other stuff and not a convoluted way to write 4 equations. Preferably, the operator should also add some new understanding to the physics.